# How many numbers are in the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: computer-science, fibonacci

Assuming I'm asked to generate Fibonacci numbers up to N, how many numbers will I generate? I'm looking for the count of Fibonacci numbers up to N, not the Nth number.

So, as an example, if I generate Fibonacci numbers up to 25, I will generate:

- 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
- that's 8 numbers

How do I calculate this mathematically for an arbitrary "n"?

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate in http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: On your suggestion, I posted this to math.stackexchange.com: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67707/how-many-numbers-are-in-the-fibonacci-sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)):

```
n(F) = Floor(Log(F * Sqrt(5) + 1/2) / Log(Phi))
```

Comment: Good enough: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67707/how-many-numbers-are-in-the-fibonacci-sequence

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the non-recursive function via the generating function. The n-th element can be calculated via the formula:

```
f(n) = (1 / Sqrt(5)) * (((1+Sqrt(5))/2)^n - ((1-Sqrt(5))/2)^n)
```

Maybe you can derive a method with this function.

Comment: As far I understood he is looking for the count of fibonacci numbers up to n but not the n-th fibonacci number...

Comment: I must confess that i did understand this too, but it might be a good starting point, although i have no clue how to go on :)

Comment: I'm looking for the count of fibonacci numbers up to N. I will make that clear in the description.